# PHPStorm - как настроить подсветку-подсказку, что файл изменен?

Tags: phpstorm

Не могу никак найти в настройках ничего подобного. Очень большие неудобства - непонятно, изменен/сохранен файл или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте включить `Mark modified tabs with asterisk` в `Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs`

Comment: большое спасибо!